# Error when trying to login to League of Legends Developer page

Tags: authentication

I am trying to make an app for League of Legends game using their WebAPI. Registered an account for LoL and when I try to access the developer page (to get API key), I get an error. It has been 2 days. The error simply says:

[image: Error]

Unfortunately their developer forum require me to login to post, but since I can't login, I can't even ask about this problem in their forum.

Does anybody has any information on this? Thank you.

**EDIT: Would appreciate it if the person who downvoted this question would explain why. The unicorn demands to know.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for anyone wondering. Turns out all you got to do is be patient and wait for a few days. In my case I tried login today and it works (I tried to login everyday). So it takes 2 days for me to be able to login after registration.

Hope this helps someone.